# On what basis was William (Willie) Alexander a member of the Government before becoming Baron Grantville

Tags: honorverse

Given that Hamish Alexander is Earl White Haven, and therefore holds the White Haven seat in the Lords, on what basis is William (Willie) Alexander first the Minister of the Exchequer and then leader of the opposition to the High Ridge government before being made Baron Grantville by the Queen after the fall of said High Ridge government?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Their family name is Alexander (Hamish and William Alexander). White Haven is part of their title.

As for being in cabinet, here's [David Weber's explanation](http://infodump.thefifthimperium.com/entry/Harrington/40/1)...

> All of the peerages above the rank of Baron are represented by two
> seats: the seat for the current holder of the title, and the "cadet"
> seat for the same peerage (held by the heir).
>
> ...
>
> The only member of a cabinet who must come from the Lords is the PM
> him/herself. The other ministers technically need not even be a member
> of Parliament, although it is traditional that all cabinet-level
> ministers are drawn from one House or the other. Willie could not have
> succeeded Cromarty in the premiership before Hamish succeeded his
> father, thus elevating Willie to the cadet White Haven seat. Of
> course, under normal circumstances, Elizabeth would have nominated
> Willie for a peerage (probably a life peerage, without right of
> inheritance) after Cromarty's death, and the Commons would undoubtedly
> have confirmed, given the Centrists' majority there, which would have
> entitled Willie to form a government. The point was moot by the time
> Cromarty actually did die, because Willie had been sitting in the
> Lords by years at that point.

Thus, William could have been appointed directly and his lack of a peerage in his own right wouldn't have been an issue. When Weber mentions him inheriting the White Haven cadet seat, that's due to his father's death (and Hamish inheriting the earldom) sometime between the first and second novels. I don't know if Weber has stated anywhere whether William was an elected Member of Parliament, and thus his appointment "traditional", or whether it was a non-traditional appointment.

(For the Americans in the audience, this is similar to the Speaker of the House. That it's an elected Representative is traditional, not necessary. Theoretically, enough Representatives could band together to nominate and elect someone else entirely.)

By the time the Duke of Cromarty was killed and William assumed the role of Prime Minister, he was seated in the Lords in the White Haven cadet seat (as Lord William Alexander) as he was heir to the Earldom of White Haven, since Hamish and Emily Alexander had no children, and was thus eligible to act as PM. Elizabeth making him a Baron was simply a way of keeping him there in the event Hamish did eventually have a child who would thus inherit the cadet seat and *disinherit* William from the Earldom, which would have removed him from the House of Lords and made him ineligible to continue as PM.

Note that one of the other cabinet ministers at the time was Dame Rachel Nageswar (listed in *[House of Steel](http://honorverse.wikia.com/wiki/House_of_Steel)*). As she only held a knighthood, she wouldn't have been seated in the House of Lords either.

Comment: Good sources. I always thought the cadet seats were junior families in the same line rather than junior members of the same immediate family. But I guess context is everything.